# rule-based pricing with ElasticSearch - Suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm new to ElasticSearch,  I am implementing a search for products whose prices are calculated based on rules according to the requested quantity.
For example:

- 1 to 5 units -> price = units * X + Y
- 6 to 10 units $ 8 -> price =
  units * Z
- 11 to 15 units $ 6 -> price = units * W

(X, Y, Z, W could be constants or formulas)

I tried to use painless to do the price calculation in query time, but it was very expensive and it takes a long time to deliver the result.

The second strategy I applied was to define a price base for each product, store it in elasticSearch, and later apply the price formula to each product (in nodejs) considering the quantity requested, this approach was better in terms of performance.

the difficulty I have now is that I need to implement a filter for prices with min and max value, but I cannot filter the products since I calculate the price after obtaining them.
I can't assign price at indexing time either because it depends on the requested quantity (n)

Do you know any fast and reliable solution that can be applied to these cases where the price of a product depends on the quantity requested and the price rules that apply from that quantity?

Thanks in advance for your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch can only do formulas with Painless (which can be extremely painfull to use and is painfully slow).

From what I understand, your second solution could be a good fit, if modified a bit. If you only have 3-categories*, you could have a price column for each like:

- Price_cat1
- Price_cat2
- Price_cat3

This way, your aggregations would be faster and your could select the correct column from node.js when the category is already known.

* If categories can change frequently, or are expected to grow to a very very large number, this probably is not the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to do the calculation in API from which you're calling ElasticSearch and there apply business logic (rules like you mentioned with price calculation depending on the number of products).

What can quickly become tricky if you stick to Elasticsearch for this is the synchronization - not only any change to product must be reflected in Elasticsearch (here I'm assuming you using Elasticsearch as a search engine - entities are probably stored somewhere else [SQL, other NoSQL]) but also any changes for business rules will have to synchronized as well. My experience is that working with Elasticsearch is tricky in general (querying is one subject, but maintenance is trickier than SQL for example).